# UK citizen applying for a Chinese tourist visa from India

Tags: visas, uk, china

I am a UK citizen and wondering if I can apply for a Chinese visa from India?

I exceed the 3-month threshold of Chinese visa validity if I apply now from the UK and I will be in India for a few months before I get to China. Will this be possible?

Do you know the process? Like could I send the application form online and then attend an interview at the Embassy at a later date? And are there same day services or will it take a couple weeks?

I've been searching but am getting indirect and different answers.

Appreciate any and all help/advice.

Comment: What will your residence status be in India? According to http://www.visaforchina.org/DEL_EN/generalinformation/faq/277128.shtml you must submit your application in the country where you lawfully reside

Comment: But I need to apply for the visa within one month of when I will enter. I know there are people who go to China during a backpacking trip but can not apply in their home country as they have been abroad for a while.

Comment: I will be in India on a 1 year double entry tourist visa